# Set a default value for shipping city and state in Woocommerce My account

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, account

In woocommerce already the shipping country in restricted to IN
On checkout the default value of Country, state & city is set
I want to do that same in my-account/edit-address/ only in shipping address
tried using this code but its not working

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields' , 'default_shipping_address' );
 
function default_shipping_address( $fields ) {
    $fields['shipping_city']['default'] = 'Mumbai';
    $fields['shipping_state']['default'] = 'Maharashtra';
    return $fields;
 
}
```

this is not working let me know what's wrong or is there any other way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Some feed back on my answer below will be really appreciated please.

Answer (score 2):

You are pretty near… As Shipping State value in WooCommerce **is a state code**, you need to replace 'Maharashtra' with 'MH' (For India) as follows:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields' , 'set_default_my_account_shipping_city_state_values' );
function set_default_my_account_shipping_city_state_values( $fields ) {
    // Targeting My account section
    if( is_account_page() ) {
        $fields['shipping_city']['default'] = 'Mumbai';
        $fields['shipping_state']['default'] = 'MH'; // <== HERE
    }

    return $fields;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Alternative: If it really doesn't work for you, you can try to use the following:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect' , 'set_default_shipping_city_and_state_values' );
function set_default_shipping_city_and_state_values( $fields ) {
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-address' ) ) {
        if ( WC()->customer->get_shipping_city() === '' ) {
            WC()->customer->Set_shipping_city('Mumbai');
        }
        
        if ( WC()->customer->get_shipping_state() === '' ) {
            WC()->customer->Set_shipping_state('MH');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even i tried disabling all plugins but still it didn't worked

Comment: @MirzaAreebBaig Maybe this is related to your theme customizations or to others customizations made by you… I have tested that on last WooCommerce version using StoreFront theme (official WooCommerce free theme)

Comment: Hey @LoicTheAztec I disabled my theme (Porto) & tried that code but still it didn't worked.

Comment: I did a fresh installation with StoreFront theme & still the fields are blank here is the screenshot= https://snipboard.io/xuZMzv.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use the address hook.

```
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'default_shipping_address' );
function default_shipping_address( $fields ) {
    $fields['shipping_city']['value'] = 'Mumbai';
    $fields['shipping_state']['value'] = 'Maharashtra';
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately this is not working i don't want to change the label but i want to add a default value i even tried your code using it like
$address_fields['state']['default'] = 'State';

still not working.

Comment: Here is a screenshot : https://prnt.sc/xfe0tc

i want to have default value in City & State already the Country is default IN

Comment: Change the above code according to your need try with that.

Comment: Tried with 'value' also but still the same not working.

Comment: other way

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'set_default_checkout_field_values' );
function set_default_checkout_field_values($fields) {
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_city']['default'] = 'Mumbai';
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_state']['default'] = 'Maharashtra';
    return $fields;
}

Comment: Tried this but not working in checkout i already have default values in checkout form
the one i'm trying now is at my-account/edit-address/shipping/